# How to convert a perl variable in a operator for make equations?

Tags: function, perl, variables, operator-keyword, equation

```
my $numA= $ARGV[0]; #5
my $numB= $ARGV[1]; #5
my $func= $ARGV[2]; #+

my $result = $numA .$func . $numB; #The result shoudl be 10

print "The result is:  $result"; # The result is: 5+5
```

I have this code and I want to get '$func' as an operator to add '$numA' with '$numB'.

Comment: You can try this also `my $result = eval("$numA $func  $numB"); ` but not recommended

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's convenient that the expression is already parsed.

```
my %ops = (
   '+' => sub { $_[0] + $_[1] },
   '-' => sub { $_[0] - $_[1] },
   '*' => sub { $_[0] * $_[1] },
   '/' => sub { $_[0] / $_[1] },
);

my ($operand1, $operand2, $operator) = @ARGV;

say $ops{$operator}->($operand1, $operand2);
```